# Magento 1.7 using category as Top Navigation at the same time sub-navigation to other menu

Tags: category, navigation, topmenu, submenu

How do I add the category as Top Navigation and at the same time it's a sub-navigation under different Top Menu. I'm using Magento 1.7. I'm not losing hope for this. I know someone here can help. Thanks!